# Change displayName of event creator in Google Calendar API PHP

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am creating a system which manages freight shipments for my client. Part of this system is to create Google Calendar events for the different deadlines for each shipment.

I am using the Google Client Library for PHP. Every event I create displays the service email address as the creator. I would like to instead display the name of the system. I know that I can emulate a different account through OAuth, but this seems like it should be unnecessary. I'm sure there are a lot of systems out there that generate and manage events and to create two accounts just to have a user-friendly name seems like a hack-ish solution.

Comment: In your calendar, go to settings->calendars->click on your calendar->edit calendar name. This changes display name of event creator. For checking display name of creator, you can also check this field "creator.displayName" in Events. If you want to change creator to different person then you should impersonate that user to this calendar. check this link https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: @SGC I want to change the display name of the user who created the event, I don't want to post as a different user. I just want the user to be "System" instead of 8721iubcw981239bcw897g128yvcw987g129ugew9u7g129u7g@developer.gserviceaccount.com (that's not my real developer account).

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I figured you might be able to create and set an EventCreator then setDisplayName but it's not working. https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Calendar_EventCreator.html